# How can I find out what the layout of my keyboard is?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xubuntu

I just bought a new keyboard. I love it, but some of the keys don't map to the symbols they say they have. How can I find out what the layout of my keyboard is? Is there some sort of list of keyboards where I can find my keyboard?

I'm using Xubuntu.

Comment: What OS? Different distros do it differently. :(

Comment: You're right. Should've told you the OS: Xubuntu. And my keyboard is a Logitech MK365, layout unknown :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about your physical keyboard and which layout it has, there is no way to find that out using software, read the manual and find out.

If you are talking about which layout you are currently using you could run `setxkbmap -query | grep layout`.

Comment: Well, actually, that depends on the keyboard. Some keyboards store their layouts locally (for the purpose of having persistent custom layouts). In these cases, it's possible that you might be able to query the keyboard for its layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Ubuntu, you can follow this guide:

- http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu

If you use a KDE based distribution (kubuntu):

Press the following keys: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then run the executable:

```
kcm_keyboard
```

And navigate to layouts.

Comment: The Ubuntu instructions are rather dated.

Answer (score 2):

in Debian/Ubuntu you can find in folders:

```
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/azerty
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/dvorak
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/fgGIod
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/include
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwerty
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwertz
```

a lot of files named NAME.kmap.gz - if you open the compressed file NAME.kmap with a text editor you'll find the mapping of each keyboard-layout.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Xfce FAQ](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq):

> What should I do to change keyboard layout?
>
> There are several options. One is to use xfce4-xkb-plugin, see
>   http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin . You
>   can also use the setxkbmap command with the two letter keyboard code
>   as argument; you can edit your X server configuration file to choose a
>   different keyboard layout (change the value after Option “XkbLayout”,
>   e.g.: Option “XkbLayout” “dvorak”).

Comment: Yes, this is nice. However, what I need is to know what my keyboard layout actually is, because I don't know which one to select from the lists :(

Comment: I know the installer can do that, but I don't know how to do it in an already installed system. :(

Answer (score 0):

I first looked on http://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-mua/test/kbd-maps.html, found my keyboard layout (105-key, Spanish) and changed the setting according to the previous answers. But I first needed to know what to change it to!